# Configure Doctrine and Zend in NetBeans IDE 7.2.1

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I am new to Zend and Doctrine.

I want to use commands of Doctrine and Zend by NetBeans run command functionality.

Like this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=3xjfbtQtDRE

How can do it?

Answer (score 1):

To configure it go to :

> **> Project properties > Frameworks** (*to the left side*) **> Doctrine2 >
>    *Enabled*** (*enable support for Doctrine2 for this project*)

To run the command, right click the project there will be option **`Doctrine2 > Run command...`**

when you are running for the first time you will have to configure the doctrine cli file and you should be good to go.

**EDIT:** When you run the command you will be prompted to associate doctrine script file I think. Else you can configure from `preferences > PHP > Doctrine2 > Doctrine2 Script:[]`. 
 All you have to do is select the doctrine cli file. In my case it is located in `vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine` (for doctrine)

Comment: How can i configure the doctrine cli file?

Comment: I have downloaded doctrine pakage from this link -
http://www.doctrine-project.org/downloads/DoctrineORM-2.3.2-full.tar.gz

which i put it in my d:/ directory. 

i used this path "d:/DoctrineORM-2.3.2/bin/doctrine.bat" in netbeans preferences > PHP > Doctrine2 >  Doctrine2 Script:[].

It work when i choose "Search" from preferences > PHP > Doctrine2.

Now the problem is that when i create new project for doctrine, project is created without any file or folder.(empty directory).
and also when go for run command functionality (right clicking on project > Doctrine2 > run command) is not working

Comment: I think we are deviating lot from your actual question. I am having a feeling this is your first time with zend framework 2 and doctrine 2.X If so use should start with zf and doctrine integration. This http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/ could help you with it.

Comment: But if this is not your first time and you already have your application running then instead of pointing to d:/Doctrine.../doctrine.bat select the file one from your project instead. New project for doctrine would obviously give you empty you can select one as doctrine enabled project but u don't get new ready zf doctrine project.